# Jquery bubbling onclick causing duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

The div `reseller-row` you see below I want to clone as many times as the user needs upon clicking `add-reseller-btn`, in my case i'm using jquery predominantly, this div is part of a bigger form allowing a user to add links to where her books are sold. The problem is, it creates a button with each new div on click (which I want) but if I click just 1 out of 15 buttons for example.

I don't just get one insert per button, every button fires a click event from just a click of one button, I only want one insert per click. After being stuck on it for ages I'm led to believe the problem is bubbling but with all the solutions ive tried, the inserting doubles each time

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7oz3vg8/4/ - Note for some reason worked on computer prior

HTML

```
<div class = "reseller-row">
    <label for = "reseller_name">Add a retailer</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "reseller_name" class = "reseller-name"></input>
    <!-- Span if user enters invalid retailer name -->
    <span></span>

    <!-- Or select retailers already in database -->
    <label for = "reseller_select">Existing retailers</label>

    <select name = "reseller_select" class = "reseller-select">

        <option name = "reseller" value = "None">None</option>
        <!-- Fill select with resellers -->
        <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
        <option name = "reseller" value = "3">Amazon</option>
        <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
        <option name = "reseller" value = "4">whitcolls</option>
        <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
        <option name = "reseller" value = "5">Yahoo</option>
    </select>
    <span></span>

    <!-- Url of retailer -->
    <label for = "reseller_url">Url</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "reseller_url" class= "reseller-url" value = ""></input>
    <span></span>

    <!-- Status of book's availability -->
    <div>
        <label for = "availability">Availability status</label>
        <select name = "availability" class = "availability">
            <option value="Available">Available</option>
            <option value="Not available yet">Not available yet</option>
        </select>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class = "add-reseller-btn" type = "button">Add Reseller</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Form allows user to add resellers to book
// When document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Get existing fields/only need to be checked, not duplicated
    // Field allowing user to enter new reseller name
    var reseller_name_field = $("<input></input>")
        .addClass("reseller-name")
        .attr("type", "text"); 

    // Select allowing user to choose pre existing resellers
    var reseller_select     = $("<select></select>")
        .addClass("reseller-select"); 

    // Field allowing user to add urls for resellers
    var reseller_url_field  = $("<input></input>") 
        .addClass("reseller-url-field")
        .attr("type", "text"); 

    // Select allowing user to choose wheither book is currently available
    var availability_select = $("<select></select>")
        .addClass("availability"); 

    /*// Button to add more resellers will only get added if javascript is working
    var add_reseller_btn    = $("<button>Add Reseller</button>")
        .addClass("add-reseller-btn")
        .attr("type", "button");*/

    // Event delegation, instructions get passed to children of container
    var div = $(document.getElementsByClassName("reseller-row"))
        // Add-reseller-btn within reseller-row container
        .on("click", ".add-reseller-btn", function(e) {
            create_row();
        });

    // Array of dom elements
    //var elems = [ reseller_name_field, reseller_select, reseller_url_field, availability_select, add_reseller_btn ];

    // Function append new row
    function create_row() {


        // True - clone data and events attached
        $(div).clone(true).insertAfter( $(".reseller-row") );
        // $(elems).appendTo(div);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `$(div).clone(true).insertAfter( $(".reseller-row"));`...

it inserts a new copy of `div` after every `reseller-row` so

```
$(div).clone(true).insertAfter( $(".reseller-row").last() );
```

---

```js
// Form allows user to add resellers to book
// When document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Field allowing user to enter new reseller name
  var reseller_name_field = $("<input></input>")
    .addClass("reseller-name")
    .attr("type", "text");

  // Select allowing user to choose pre existing resellers
  var reseller_select = $("<select></select>")
    .addClass("reseller-select");

  // Field allowing user to add urls for resellers
  var reseller_url_field = $("<input></input>")
    .addClass("reseller-url-field")
    .attr("type", "text");

  // Select allowing user to choose wheither book is currently available
  var availability_select = $("<select></select>")
    .addClass("availability");

  /*// Button to add more resellers will only get added if javascript is working
 var add_reseller_btn    = $("<button>Add Reseller</button>")
  .addClass("add-reseller-btn")
  .attr("type", "button");*/

  // Event delegation, instructions get passed to children of container
  var div = $('.reseller-row')
    // Add-reseller-btn within reseller-row container
    .on("click", ".add-reseller-btn", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target, e)
      create_row();
    });

  // Array of dom elements
  //var elems = [ reseller_name_field, reseller_select, reseller_url_field, availability_select, add_reseller_btn ];

  // Function append new row
  function create_row() {
    // True - cloen data and events attached
    $(div).clone(true).insertAfter($(".reseller-row").last());
    // $(elems).appendTo(div);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reseller-row">
  <label for="reseller_name">Add a retailer</label>
  <input type="text" name="reseller_name" class="reseller-name" />
  <!-- Span if user enters invalid retailer name -->
  <span></span>

  <!-- Or select retailers already in database -->
  <label for="reseller_select">Existing retailers</label>

  <select name="reseller_select" class="reseller-select">

    <option name="reseller" value="None">None</option>
    <!-- Fill select with resellers -->
    <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
    <option name="reseller" value="3">Amazon</option>
    <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
    <option name="reseller" value="4">whitcolls</option>
    <!-- If select has been submitted and its value equals what came back(saved) from post -->
    <option name="reseller" value="5">Yahoo</option>
  </select>
  <span></span>

  <!-- Url of retailer -->
  <label for="reseller_url">Url</label>
  <input type="text" name="reseller_url" class="reseller-url" value="" />
  <span></span>

  <!-- Status of book's availability -->
  <div>
    <label for="availability">Availability status</label>
    <select name="availability" class="availability">
      <option value="Available">Available</option>
      <option value="Not available yet">Not available yet</option>
    </select>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="add-reseller-btn" type="button">Add Reseller</button>
  </div>
</div>
```